# Drag and Drop into a textbox

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, drag-and-drop

I have a list of people on the left hand side of a page, this list is populated by PHP.

Each person is in their own div (this can be changed but I thought div's may be easier to work with). I want to be able to drag any one of these people onto a textbox, thus entering their name into that textbox.

Also to make it more awkward, I don't really want to be using jQuery or prototype. Or any of the others really.

**Edit:**
Sorry let me rephrase the question...
How would I check to see if something has been dragged on top of a textbox? And how would I get the ID of that element?

What I don't know is how to check if something has been dragged on top of the textbox (input box, not text area, but that's no big issue.)
I know there would never be a magical param like `onDragOnto=""` but hopefully that will show you what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more details, I can't really provide a better answer.

How about clicking within the DIV element resulting in a Javascript event to be fired which causes the element's text to be selected?  Then, you can drag this text into a multiline textarea.

Now, with the information from the edit:

You'd register a onmousedown event with each DIV that you have.

On the names:

```
<div onmousedown="onMouseDown(event);" onmouseup="onMouseUp(event);">Jane</div>
```

On the textarea/textbox:

```
<textarea onmouseover="return onMouseOver(event);"></textarea>
```

And a script:

```
<script>

function onMouseOver(evt) {
    target = document.lastClicked;
    if (target != null) {
        window.alert(target.id);
    }
}

function onMouseDown(evt) {
    document.lastClicked = window.event.target;
}

function onMouseUp(evt) {
    document.lastClicked = null;
}

</script>
```

This is a very crude way to do things, but I hope this gives you the principles that you're looking for.  If you want to force the elements to move rather than just using text drag-and-drop, then things get more hairy.  To handle that, you'll need to use CSS and modify the coordinates.

Comment: Sorry let me refraze the question.

How would I check to see if something has been dragged on top of a textbox? And how would I get the ID of that element?

Comment: Please edit your question and clarify there, or add a comment below your question.  It makes it easier for other people to see it.  I will be editing my answer to match your comment here.

Comment: :) Thanks I actually did that just before your comment :) But thanks for the heads up.
Thanks in advance for your answer, and sorry I'm new to this site and still havent figured it out that well :]

Comment: Thanks, will check it later as I'm on my phone. But looking at it, it should work.... Thanks